# Function returns before variable is defined

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have a simple series of functions :

```
    convertXML();

    function convertXML(){

        var xmlObj = xmlToJson(xml.responseXML)
            .query.results.WMS_Capabilities;
        console.log("convertXML");

        (function checkReturn(){
            if(typeof xmlObj != 'undefined'){
            return (function(){ return createData(xmlObj)})();
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(checkReturn, 50);
            }
        })();
    }

    function createData(xmlObj){
        for (var i = 0; i < xmlObj.Capability.Layer.Layer.length; i++){
            var row={};
            row = xmlObj.Capability.Layer.Layer[i];
            WMSLayers.push(row);
        };
        console.log("createdata",WMSLayers)

        return (function(){return finish()})();
    }

    function finish(){
        console.log(n == Server.length-1)
        if (n == Server.length-1){
            //n is defined as an argument
            //this code is a part of a bigger function
            //same for Server variable
                createTable();

            };
    }
```

The problem is that that the `convertXML` function sometimes returns the callback function `createData` with the `xmlObj` variable `undefined`. So I have to check if the variable is defined to call the callback function.

My question is isn't a function suppose to return when all its variables are finished loading data?

**UPDATE**

This is how I make the request:

```
var req = {
    "type"    :"GET",
    "dataType":"XML",
    "data"    : null,
    "url"     : url
};

//make the request (ajax.js)
ajax(req,ajaxSuccess,ajaxError);

function ajax(prop,onsuccess,onerror){
// data = data || null;
// var url = "wps"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
    type: prop.type,
    dataType: prop.dataType,
    data: prop.data,
    url: prop.url,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr)
        onsuccess(xhr);
    },
    error:function (data ,textStatus, xhr) {
        onerror(xhr);
    }

});
// e.preventDefault();
}

function ajaxSuccess(xhr){
    $("#messages").append(
        '<span style="color:blue">' +
        getFullTime() + 
        '</span> Response HTTP status <b>' + 
        xhr.status + 
        ' [' + xhr.statusText + ']' +
        '</b> from:' +
        ' <a style="color:grey;text-decoration:none;" href="' +
        url+
        '" target="_blank">'+
        Server[i].link + 
        Request["getCapabilities"]+
        '</a><br>'
    );

    //create the wms
    createWMS(xhr, Server[i],i);//this is where the convertXML,createData and finish functions are located

        };
```

Comment: Wow ..... just ...... -> `return (function(){return finish()})();` whoa !

Comment: Where is `xml` defined?

Comment: You seem to be dealing with something async, hence the need to use a recursive function to check if it's done, which is probably not the best approach

Comment: On the other hand, if [this](https://github.com/metatribal/xmlToJSON) is the `xmlToJson` you're using, it's not async at all, but `xml.responseXML` looks like it might be.

Comment: `finish()` used to have parameters thats why is in function(){} :P

Comment: [this](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json) is the `xmlToJson`

Comment: The xml is defined from `xml.responseXML` from the `success:` property of jquery ajax

Comment: And jQuery ajax is asynchronous, so you're running this code in the callback right, you're not using timeouts to gauge when the ajax request is done ?

Comment: no i not..  how can i do that.? and is this different somehow from the timeouts i am using? I am refering at the performace of the program

Comment: Where is `n` defined within `finish`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `complete` function of `$.get()`. Note, `n` does not appear to be defined within `finish` function.

```
function convertXML(xml, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  var xmlObj = xmlToJson(jqxhr.responseXML)
               .query.results.WMS_Capabilities;
  console.log("convertXML");

  if (typeof xmlObj != 'undefined') {
      createData(xmlObj);
  }
}

function createData(xmlObj){
  for (var i = 0; i < xmlObj.Capability.Layer.Layer.length; i++){
      var row = xmlObj.Capability.Layer.Layer[i];
      WMSLayers.push(row);
   };
   console.log("createdata",WMSLayers)
   finish();
}

$.get("/path/to/resource",  convertXML, "xml")
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(errorThrown)
});
```

Comment: thanks for the get() function mentioned. But not solvin my problem.. I need to have access to the response data `jqxhr` also at the callback like at `.fail()`

Comment: @mrapsogos _"But not solvin my problem.. I need to have access to the response data `jqxhr` also at the callback like at `.fail()`"_ ? `jqxhr` is available at `convertXML` callback

Comment: The updated `javascript` appears entirely different from original `javascript`? Use the third parameter at `ajaxSuccess`. That is `function ajaxSuccess(data, textStatus, xhr){`, where `xhr` is `jqXHR` object; `data` is actual `xml` response. It is also still necessary to define the parameter at `convertXML`, e.g., `convertXML(xml)`. At `javascript` at updated Question, `xhr` is `xml` `document` or `text`, not `jqXHR` jQuery promise object